# Excel VBA AutoFill dynamic range and increment by 10

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

Is there a way to have AutoFill increment by 10 instead of 1? The following code functions in my worksheet. The user (geologist) defines a beginning station number in B1 and an end station number in B2. The macro is run and beginning with C5, the column is populated with station numbers from the beginning to the end station. However, data only needs to be collected every 10 stations, and I have not been able to figure out how to incorporate that into my code. Instead of 1000, 1001, 1002...etc., I would like 1000, 1010, 1020...

```
Sub StationFill()

Dim taskStationEnd As Long
Dim taskStationBegin As Long

taskStationBegin = Range("B1").Value
taskStationEnd = Range("B2").Value

With Worksheets("Data")
    .Columns(3).ClearContents
    Set SourceRange = .Range("C5")
    SourceRange.Value = taskStationBegin
    Set fillRange = .Range(SourceRange, _
      Cells(SourceRange.Row + taskStationEnd - taskStationBegin, SourceRange.Column))
    SourceRange.AutoFill Destination:=fillRange, Type:=xlFillSeries
End With

End Sub
```

(First time poster. Not sure I formatted correctly and got the code line breaks in the right place)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub marine()
    Dim taskStationEnd As Long
    Dim taskStationBegin As Long
    Dim SourceRange As Range

    Const interval As Long = 10 '<~~ this is your interval

    With Sheets("Sheet1") '<~~ change to suit
        taskStationBegin = .Range("B1").Value
        taskStationEnd = .Range("B2").Value
        Set SourceRange = .Range("C5")
        SourceRange = taskStationBegin
        SourceRange.Offset(1, 0) = taskStationBegin + interval
        SourceRange.Resize(2).AutoFill _
            SourceRange.Resize(((taskStationEnd - taskStationBegin) / interval) + 1) _
            , xlFillSeries
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked great. I need to think more about how the SourceRange Offset and Resize are working to fully understand your solution, but am glad to have something to pick apart and understand rather than what I cobbled together.

Comment: @AnnaNmty *Offset* works like you are pressing arrow keys. So `.Offset(1, 0)` means you move the target cell 1 row from the reference which is your *Range Object*. Resize is like pressing arrow keys while holding *Shift*. `.Resize(2)` means you expand selection to 2 rows. I omitted the column argument since there is no need to resize the number of columns. If it is the other way around then you omit row argument like this `.Resize(, 2)`.

Comment: I now have a similar task only this time autofilling a row instead of a column. Based on my understanding of your explanation, I changed the offset to `.Offset(0, 1)` and my resize to `.Resize(, 2)`.  I get an error description of "AutoFill method of Range class failed."

Any help with understanding how to correct this is appreciated.

Comment: @AnnaNmty Ah you almost had it. You just need to change this line as well `SourceRange.Resize(((taskStationEnd - taskStationBegin) / interval) + 1)` to `SourceRange.Resize(, ((taskStationEnd - taskStationBegin) / interval) + 1)`

Comment: THANK YOU! That was driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried with Excel 2010 and there is a increment value available (step).

```
Range("A1:A26").DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, **Step:=10**
```

Maybe it helps you.

Kind regards,
Christof

Comment: I was not able to figure out how to make Step work for my task, but thank you for letting me know it existed! I have some reading and learning to do.